# Cast is not Valid - Object Array to a Double Array

Tags: c#, arrays

When i tried to convert object array to a double array it throws an exception saying cast is not valid.  please help.

below is my code;

object array

```
var uptime = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["Up_tome_convert"]).ToArray();
```

i was trying to convert uptime to uptime_double

```
double[] uptime_double = Array.ConvertAll<object, double>(uptime, x => (double)x);
```

Comment: See `Convert.ToDouble()` or `Double.Parse()`.

Comment: You can only unbox an `object` to a `double` if it **was** a boxed `double`; so: what was the original value in the box? As @Dan says, `Convert.ToDouble` may be your friend here

Comment: Use `row.Field<type>("Up_tome_convert")` to get typed values from rows. This does require that you know the actual type of the column (which, in this case, apparently is not `double`, though it might still be `double?`), but knowing that is generally a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object should be castable to double without Convert to do that. Looks like you are dealing with a field that is not directly castable to a double. You could do this (if up_tome_convert is an int):

```
var uptime = dt.AsEnumerable()
   .Select(dr => Convert.ToDouble(dr.Field<int>("Up_tome_convert")))
   .ToArray();
```